# How to increase number of available SMB requests in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, smb, matlab

I use an program (Matlab) which is giving errors about exhausting the number of change notification handles (CNH), known in Windows as server message blocks ([SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)). Matlab's tech support said that MATLAB uses CNHs to track if a file has been updated in a directory and by default Windows 7 has 50 CNHs available.

How can I increase the number of SMBs on my Windows 7 machine? [This solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926646) is out of date (XP is no longer maintained) and did not work for [this user](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-networking/exhausting-change-notification-handles-smb/880d04e6-e35a-4a1e-94cd-5ac073c24ec9).

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/929973/1990878

Comment: Good for giving background - I never heard of SMBs until Matlab gave this error!